# How to add a GLSurfaceView to an Android maps v2 marker InfoWindow

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, android-maps-v2

Are there any restrictions as to what types of custom Views can be used in an Android maps v2 marker InfoWindow? While I have been able to add many types of views, I have not been able to add a GLSurfaceView.

Android maps v2 allows for custom views in a marker's InfoWindow. I understand that the GLSurfaceView will not be interactive in any way, as the Android dev site states:

> The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered
>   as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is returned

but I thought that it would at least capture the GLSurfaceView as an image as it exists right when InfoWindow.getInfoContents() is called, but the InfoWindow is only black where the GLSurfaceView would be.

Any ideas?